# Work unbalance on OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a loop of the kind

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j)
for(i=0;i<N;i++){  //N is very large
 for(j=0;j<i;j++){
   //do some work here
 }
}
```

using OpenMP directives.

The main problem is that as `i` gets large the innermost loop has more work to do. Since by default the loops gets parallelized by assigning to each thread a contiguous chunk of the iterations of the principal for loop (i.e. if using 2 threads only thread1 gets assigned i=0..N/2-1 and thread2 gets assigned i=N/2..N-1) the last thread will always have more work than the first one resulting in load unbalancing between threads.

I have read that one way to control this kind of behaviour is by means of the Scheduling clauses `schedule(type,chunk)` where `type` can be static, dynamic or guided. The problem is that I don't understand the behaviour of the `schedule` clause and their different types so I am unable to use it properly. (Illustrative examples would do the trick)

In particular, I would be interested in assigning to each thread alternate chunks of iterations, so that all of them receive iterations from the lower range of `i`as long as from its higher range, to equal the job that each thread is doing. For instance, if using 4 threads I would like something like this to happen

```
thread1: i=0,4,8...
thread2: i=1,5,9...
thread3: i=2,6,10...
thread4: i=3,7,11...
```

although other approaches to the problem are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have inner loops that depend on the number of iterations of the outer loop I think you want to used `schedule(guided)`.  **Edit: I now think `schedule(static,1) may be best since it balances the load and has less overhead than the dynamic schedulers.  See the end of answer.**  I mean either

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
       //do some work here
    }
}
```

or

```
for(i=0;i<N-1;i++) {
    for(j=i+1;j<N;j++){
       //do some work here
    }
}
```

Both of these run over a triangle of numbers (either top down or bottom up) and do order N*(N+1)/2 iterations.  Let's look at what happens when you use `schedule(static)` with 2 threads for N = 8 on your code.

```
schedule (static): thread 1 i = 0-3, thread 2 i = 4-7
thread 1: chunck_size = 4
    i = 1, j = 0
    i = 2, j = 0, 1
    i = 3, j = 0, 1, 2
    iterations = 1+2+3 = 6
thread 2: chunck_size = 4
    i = 4, j = 0, 1, 2, 3
    i = 5, j = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
    i = 6, j = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    i = 7, j = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    iterations = 4+5+6+7 = 22
```

The first thread does 6 iterations and the second thread does 22 iterations so the load is not balanced (assuming the work for each iterations is equal).  Now let's look at `schedule(guided)`.  With guided each successive thread gets `number_of_iterations_remaining / number_of_threads`.

```
schedule (guided):
thread 1: chunk size = 8/2 = 4
    i = 1, j = 0
    i = 2, j = 0, 1
    i = 3, j = 0, 1, 2
    iterations = 1+2+3 = 6
thread 2: chunk size = 4/2 = 2
    i = 4, j = 0, 1, 2, 3
    i = 5, j = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
    iterations = 4+5 = 9
thread 1: chunk size = 2/2 = 1
    i = 6, j = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    iterations = 6
thread 2: chunk size = 1
    i = 7, j = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    iterations = 7
```

Now the load is better balance.  As `i` increase the number of iterations `j` to run over increase as well but with `guided` the chunk size decreases with each thread so the combination of these two things flattens out the number of iterations per thread.

Edit:

```
schedule (static,1):
thread 1: i = 1, j = 0
thread 2: i = 2, j = 0, 1
thread 1: i = 3, j = 0, 1, 2
thread 2: i = 4, j = 0, 1, 2, 3
thread 1: i = 5, j = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
thread 2: i = 6, j = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
thread 1: i = 7, j = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

thread 1 does 1+3+5+7 = 16 iterations
thread 2 does 2+4+6 = 12 iterations.
**If we define `n = N/num_threads` then in general thread 1 does `n^2` iterations (since the sum of the odd numbers is a square) and thread 2 will do `(n-1)*n` iterations**.  In this case n = 4.  So thread 1 does 4^2=16 iterations, and thread2 does 3*4=12 iterations so we see the formula is right.  For example if N = 200 and num_threads=2 then thread1 will do 100^2 =10000 iterations and thread2 will do 99*100=9900 iterations.  So the load is more or less balanced.

Comment: What about the `schedule(static,1)`? How does it work? Would each thread fetch only 1 iteration each time and then ask for the next iteration to get? Or would all the iterations be distributed at start?

Comment: `static` does not dynamically determine the iterations it does it at the start.  But it's worth trying `schedule(static,1)` to see how it performs.  With `schedule(static,1)` thread(n+1) does one more iteration than thread (n) so as n get's larger it will be more balanced.

Comment: Now that I look at your example with detail, you say that with `guided` each thread fetches `number_of_iterations_remaining / number_of_threads`. Assuming 8 iterations and 4 threads, wouldn't the first one get only 2 iterations and not 4 as you pointed out? I assume then that the example is made with only 2 threads and so thread3=thread1 and thread4=thread2 that will ask for more iterations once they finish their first batch.

Comment: I assumed only two thread.  When I wrote thread 3 I meant the second iterations of of thread 1...I edited the text.

Comment: I added some text on `schedule(static,1)`.

Comment: I was thinking of an approach in which one thread picks the i=0 and i=N-1 and the next thread picks i=1 and i=N-2 and so on. This would be more balanced I think but I don't know on how to implement it. Another topic is whether or not it would be better than the `guided`approach...

Comment: @gunbl4d3, I now think Massimiliano is probably right.  Just use `schedule(static,1)`.  The dynamic schedulers (dynamic and guided) have a larger overhead and therefore are only useful when you can't balance the load with static but in this case `schedule(static,1)` works well so use that.

Comment: where can i get the algorithms for these scheduling

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the result you are aiming for you should use:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) schedule(static,1)
for(i=0;i<N;i++){  //N is very large
 for(j=0;j<i;j++){
   //do some work here
 }
}
```

In fact, according to the standard (OpenMP 4.0):

> When **schedule(static, chunk_size )** is specified, iterations are divided
>   into chunks of size chunk_size, and the chunks are assigned to the
>   threads in the team in a round-robin fashion in the order of the
>   thread number.

Apart from this, I would suggest trying `dynamic` and `guided` schedules which will move the balancing logic from a static (and reproducible) mapping to the run-time system.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to know the behaviour of all the `schedule` options so that I can tune it to my needs knowing what I am doing and not just relying on the output. That's why I asked for `illustrative examples`.

Comment: @gunbl4d3 You'll find a neat description of the schedule types in table 2.1 of the [standard](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf), plus a lot of examples in the [OpenMP 4.0 examples](http://openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.Examples.pdf)

Comment: @Massimiliano, now that I think about it `schedule(static,1)` may be a better choice than `schedule(guided)` in this case.  It would be interesting to compare the two and see which works best.

Comment: I am going to try both cases in my code and see what happens. I will post the results when I have time to do the tests.

Comment: No scheduling: 47.97sec. `schedule(static,1)`:45.04 sec. `schedule(guided)`:44.85 sec.

Comment: I added some more text.  If there are two threads then with `schedule(static,1) one thread will do roughly twice as much work as the other therefore I think schedule(guided) might be still best.

Comment: @gunbl4d3, I made a mistake in my calculation for the number of iterations for thread2 in `schedule(static,1)`.  The load is more or less balanced with `schedule(static,1)`.